# How to check the errorlog for important messages

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2017, monitoring, error-log

I would like to receive an email every day from each of "my" SQL Servers, with information from the ErrorLog.

I would like an easy way to determine if there is any **important new** information, that I should not overlook.

So I've tried to categorise all the messages into "Database Backup", "Reboot", "Noise" etc. All un-categorised messages I list as "Unusual event".

I've been looking for some time for a list of messages that it is safe to ignore, but found none. So here is my list.

Am I pruning the list too hard?
Are there other messages that I should ignore?
Can you point me to other methods, that work better?

here is my code: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/HenrikSPoulsenBaader/782c8538156585a4c3b31fdb668f9c26)

Comment: Going through sys.messages would probably help you come up with a better list of what to include.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik; yes that is a good idea. Thank you. But how to categorise them?
And there are 13255 in each language...

Comment: "Critical" and "Not Critical"

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik; and it is not all of them that can appear in the ErrorLog, as in "TOP is not allowed in an UPDATE or DELETE statement against a partitioned view.". But I could go by Severity

Comment: Okay, serious question: If you've already set up alerts for [high severity and corruption](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/configure-sql-server-alerts/), what are you looking in the error log for? Really think about what matters in your environment. I don't think it's a question anyone can answer for you.

Comment: I guess a good use case would be doing "[trend analysis of sql server logs](https://livestream.com/gaelcolas/PSConfAsia/videos/182137059)". Categorizing is hard part that you have to do manually. This will be specific to your needs. Check the link that shows how to do it using Powershell.

Comment: I think you are in for some hard work here, Henrik. I use Agent alerts for the stuff I want to get emails from (I have a script for that on my web-site). And then I *manually* now and then go through the errolog to find "weird things", using another script on my we-site.

Comment: @Kin; It is a nice video, but where are the links to Powershell?
@sp_BlitzErik; I do have alerts set up, but I thought there would be other interesting stuff in the ErrorLog?
@TiborKaraszi; Thank you very much, it was just what I was looking for.